# Multiple screen resolution support in cocos2d v3?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone

I am little confused with cocos2d v3's support for multiple screen resolutions. If I use `CCSetupScreenMode: CCScreenModeFlexible`, what should be the default resolution of the image that I provide?

Currently, I have provided assets for all the iOS device resolutions along with suffixes and the correct images are loaded on iPhone "3.5inch" and iPad. However, the "-568h@2x" suffix for iPhone "4 inch" is not working fine. Am i using the wrong suffix?

I would like to avoid the need to use macros to determine which device the game is running on and load the images accordingly.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The ScreenMode only defines if the screen scales up with the device size or not.

The `fixed screen` mode provides you with a stage that has a *safe* area and an *unsafe* area but the complete stage always has the same size.

In the `flexible screen mode` the root node of your scene will resize with the actual screen size, so you have to deal with dynamic sizing.

You can read more about the screen modes, image sizes and how to design a game for multiple screen resolutions in [our tutorial](https://www.makegameswith.us/gamernews/361/dynamic-layouts-with-spritebuilder-and-cocos2d-30).

In Cocos2D the suffixes are different from the ones UIKit uses. The suffixes are:

- -ipad
- -ipadhd
- -hd
- -iphone5hd

Comment: Thankyou so much for the answer! I had my game running on the iPhone   5 simulator in no time. Silly of me to not notice the naming convention difference between the other suffixes and the iphone5 one!

Comment: any idea for iphone 6 plus?   -iphone5hd suffix works just fine with iphone 6

Comment: Support for iPhone 6 and iPhone 6 plus assets will have to be added to future versions of Cocos2D. For now `-iphone5hd` will work because iOS scales Apps up automatically, however the resolution will not be as high as possible.