# After migrating to cocos2d v3 background image is scaled 2x

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

I have strange problem in cocos2d v3, probably some misconfiguration which I was unable to find in google.

I'm adding background for iphone5 which is 640X1136

```
CCSprite *background = [CCSprite spriteWithImageNamed:@"background_iphone5.png"];
background.positionType = CCPositionTypeNormalized;
background.position = ccp(0.5f, 0.5f); 
[self addChild:background];
```

but it is scaled up about 2x times so doesn't fits the screen. Same image worked perfectly in cocos2d v2

Please help

Comment: I think you have to add the necessary suffix. Check out this answer for naming conventions : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22286153/multiple-screen-resolution-support-in-cocos2d-v3 . This is probably a feature because if you do not include the hd image than you would want your images to scale up.

Comment: Cool. I will add an answer in order for other people experiencing similar issues in the future to be able to get the info faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cocos2d, like `UIKit`s `@2x` uses suffixes to differentiate images intended for different screen sizes and resolutions.

These are the ones used by Cocos2d :

- ipad
- ipadhd
- hd
- iphone5hd

So you would have to add the appropriate image for your display with the suffix into your bundle like `background_iphone5.png`.

In your use case Cocos2d is resizing your *non-retina* image to a *retina* size (2x height, 2x width).

For consistency reasons this is a desired behaviour. 
Consider the case of somebody not *non-retina* resources exclusively: all the sprites would be 2 times smaller on retina displays, which would probably get your game logics out of whack.

I highly suggest using `SpriteBuiler` because all this resizing and naming behaviour is integrated into the tool and works seamlessly. You only create retina ipad resolution images and it resizes them for you automatically.